# Posting a form from Rails programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I go about creating and posting a form POST request from inside some Rails code?
The use case I have is that I have received a form request, and I would like to forward this request on to a third party with my parameters intact.

I should add that I want to redirect the user out to the third party with the form too.

Comment: I suspect you have no control over the third party and can't make any changes to it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to do this via Javascript, as there is no way of redirecting a POST request ([as per the HTTP/1.1 protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)).

Answer (score 1):

From [ruby docs for Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html):

```
 res = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://www.example.com/search.cgi'),
                              {'q'=>'ruby', 'max'=>'50'})
```

You could just pass params as the second arg, eg:

```
 Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://www.example.com/search.cgi'), params)
 redirect_to some_path
```

Also, don't forget to require the lib:

```
 require 'net/http'
 require 'uri'
```

Comment: This only appears to submit the form and return the response to my app.  I want to send the user off with the form.

Comment: Then why not just have the form's action attr point to the url you'd like to POST them to?

Comment: Because I need to do some processing on the data before the third party

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it this way:

1. receive the post form the user

   - change whatever data you mean to
   - respond to the request with a form full of hidden fields
   - automatically post that form to the third party via javascript on dom-loaded

Alternatively:

1. set the form action to be the third party url
2. intercept the onsubmit event with js

   - change whatever data you need, either by simple client-side manipulation of the form
   - or, post an ajax request to your app to treat the data, and replace the fields you need with from the ajax response
   - with the data now massaged, let the form go through to the third party